# Воспроизведение музыки

Tags: аудио, java

Вот в лаунчере для майнкрафта надыбал. Сюдя по этой программе куда написать имя файла который будет воспроизводится. Пусть имя файла будет electro.mp3.

```
package net.minecraft;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
public class MusPlay {
private String filename;
private Player player;

// constructor that takes the name of an MP3 file
public MusPlay(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

public void close() { if (player != null) player.close(); }

// play the MP3 file to the sound card
public void play() {
    try {
        InputStream is=getClass().getResourceAsStream(setting.iMusicname);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        player = new Player(is);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem playing file " + filename);
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    // run in new thread to play in background
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try { player.play(); }
            catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
        }
    }.start();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

В конструктор передайте путь к файлу, а потом вызовите метод `play();`